# How do I select an item in a drop down box (Selenium, Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having trouble trying to find how to select a certain items within a drop down box, I am using Python and Selenium with a ChromeDriver. 
I can get the drop down box to open, but cant select any of the items.

Comment: Is it a plain html `<select>` (or some fancy ajax widget)?

Comment: use driver.find_element_by_link_text("dropdown menu") for clicking on the dropdown menu, and then again use driver.find_element_by_link_text("item")

Comment: It is in html but i not sure weather it will be link to some Ajax. and thanks avasal but didnt seem to work.

Comment: I think we need some more information on how the HTML looks to be able to help you.

Comment: sorry i have resolved this problem now. http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver i followed this and just used the code time.sleep(2)